# JAXB unmarshaling does not work on @XmlElement which have xmlns attribute

Tags: java, kotlin, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have 2 xml files...

First one is...

```xml
<parent>
    <child>TEXT</child>
</parent>
```

Second one is the same but with attribute xmlns...

```xml
<parent>
   <child xmlns="...">TEXT</child>
</parent>
```

And the bindings are such...

```kotlin
@XmlRootElement(name = "child")
class Child {

    @XmlValue
    val value: String? = null
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
class Parent {

    @XmlElement
    val child: Child? = null
}
```

##### If I use first XML I can read `TEXT` from the `child` and everything works...

##### But if I use second XML I can't read TEXT and result is `null`

### Why on heavens earth I can't read TEXT from the child if it has `xmlns` attribute on?

---

Here is the whole code that fails to read the `TEXT`...

```kotlin
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream

@XmlRootElement(name = "child")
class Child {

    @XmlValue
    val value: String? = null
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
class Parent {

    @XmlElement
    val child: Child? = null

}

fun main() {
    val targetStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(
        """
            <parent>
                <child ="...">TEXT</child>
            </parent> 
        """.toByteArray()
    )
    val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent::class.java)
    val parent = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(targetStream) as Parent
    println(parent.child?.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for anyone who came to the same problem...

```kotlin
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
class Parent {

    @XmlElement
    val child: Child? = null
}
```

If the child has `xmlns` attribute on it you have to define parent like such...

```kotlin
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
class Parent {

    @XmlElement(namespace="<xmlns url>")
    val child: Child? = null
}
```